# MS Access 64 bit will not run queries which ran under 32 bit

Tags: microsoft-office, 64-bit, microsoft-access

I am running MS Access 2016 in Office. Yesterday I un-installed the 32 bit version and installed 64 bit Office and Access. Now Access will not run. 
As a specific case, I have created a query using the function

```
Rep: Replace([field1],"s","a")
```

Which gives me `#Error` with no further information.

If I use the textbook example

```
a: InStr("Hello","L")
```

It gives me error *"Argument Count Mismatch"*.

I have created Table1 with one field Field1 containing `"Name___Surname"`.

Function

```
b: InStr([Table1]![Field1],"_")
```

Gives me `#Error`.

The SQL for the last example is

```
SELECT Table1.Field1, InStr([Table1]![Field1],"_") AS b
FROM Table1;
```

This also gives me `#Error`.

Do I need to re-install the 32 bit version or should I persist trying to get the 64 bit version to work?

Answer (score 1):

To decide which version, read [Choose between the 64-bit or 32-bit](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261#32or64Bit=Office_2016) .

If you still want to use x64 read the  [Compatibility Inspector user's guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2010/ee833946(v=office.14))

- Office x64 needs matching libaries (references), or prevents VBA-Functions to work, like`Replace()` Check Tools->References in VBA-Ide for not working links to libaries (the one for VBA is the first, and if one is not working, all are broken.)
- Win-API calls needs to be [converted to x64](https://jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp)
- ActiveX-Controls need an x64 version.